# Questions with multiple matches in the same Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have the following graph

```
CREATE 
(n1:Person {name: "David Wallace", role: "CFO", dept: "management"}),
(n2:Person {name: "Ryan Howard", role: "VP, North East Region", dept: "management"}),
(n3:Person {name: "Toby Flenderson", role: "HR Rep.", dept: "HR"}),
(n4:Person {name: "Michael Scott", role: "Regional Manager", dept: "management"}),
(n5:Person {name: "Todd Pecker", role: "Travel Sales Rep.", dept: "Sales"}),
(n6:Person {name: "Angela Martin", role: "Senior Accountant", dept: ["Accounting", "Party Planning Committee"]}),
(n7:Person {name: "Dwight Schrute", role: ["Sales", "Assistant to the Regional Manager"], dept: "Sales"}),
(n8:Person {name: "Jim Halpert", role: ["Sales", "Assistant Regional Manager"], dept: "Sales"}),
(n9:Person {name: "Pam Beesley", role: "Receptionist", dept: "Reception"}),
(n10:Person {name: "Creed Barton", role: "Quality Assurance Rep.", dept: "Quality Control"}),
(n11:Person {name: "Darryl Philbin", role: "Warehouse Foreman", dept: "Warehouse"}),
(n12:Person {name: "Kevin Malone", role: "Accountant", dept: "Accounting"}),
(n13:Person {name: "Oscar Martinez", role: "Accountant", dept: "Accounting"}),
(n14:Person {name: "Meredith Palmer", role: "Supplier Relations", dept: "Supplier Relations"}),
(n15:Person {name: "Kelly Kapoor", role: "Customer Service Rep.", dept: "Customer Service"}),
(n16:Person {name: "Jerry DiCanio", dept: "Warehouse"}),
(n17:Person {name: "Madge Madsen", dept: "Warehouse"}),
(n18:Person {name: "Lonnie Collins", dept: "Warehouse"}),
(n19:Person {name: "Andy Bernard", role: "Regional Director in Sales", dept: "Sales"}),
(n20:Person {name: "Phyllis Lapin", role: "Sales", dept: "Sales"}),
(n21:Person {name: "Stanley Hudson", role: "Sales", dept: "Sales"}),
(n1)-[:manages]->(n2),
(n2)-[:manages]->(n3),
(n2)-[:manages]->(n4),
(n2)-[:manages]->(n5),
(n4)-[:manages]->(n6),
(n4)-[:manages]->(n7),
(n4)-[:manages]->(n8),
(n4)-[:manages]->(n9),
(n4)-[:manages]->(n10),
(n4)-[:manages]->(n11),
(n4)-[:manages]->(n14),
(n4)-[:manages]->(n15),
(n6)-[:manages]->(n12),
(n6)-[:manages]->(n13),
(n8)-[:manages]->(n19),
(n11)-[:manages]->(n16),
(n11)-[:manages]->(n17),
(n11)-[:manages]->(n18),
(n19)-[:manages]->(n20),
(n19)-[:manages]->(n21);
```

and I have the following query

> Does Michael directly manage more employees than Jim Halpert?

I come up with the following Cypher query

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[:manages]-(n:Person)
WHERE n.name = "Michael Scott"
MATCH (q:Person)<-[:manages]-(m:Person)
WHERE m.name = "Jim Halpert"
RETURN count(p) > count(q)
```

The query returns `false`. I checked both `count(p)` and `count(q)` are 8. I was wondering why is this? Also, what's the scope of `MATCH` statement meaning will `p` and `q` bind to the different variables (i.e., variable only visible in the MATCH statement scope; I can re-use the same variable for different MATCH statement)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach when chaining more `MATCH` clauses is to use `WITH` statement that separates query parts explicitly, allowing you to declare which variables to carry over to the next part.

In your case:

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[:manages]-(n:Person)
WHERE n.name = "Michael Scott"
WITH count(p) AS countP
MATCH (q:Person)<-[:manages]-(m:Person)
WHERE m.name = "Jim Halpert"
RETURN countP > count(q)
```

Answer (score 2):

The two matches in your query are forming a catrtesian product, returning one **p** for each **q** (1 x 8). If you substitute **Darryl Philbin** for **Jim Halpert** you will appear to get 24 counts for each **p** and **q** (3 x 8).

You will see what's happening more clearly if you run:

```
MATCH (p:Person)<-[:manages]-(n:Person)
WHERE n.name = "Michael Scott"
MATCH (q:Person)<-[:manages]-(m:Person)
WHERE m.name = "Jim Halpert"
RETURN p.name, q.name
```

As Lukasmp3 says, introducing a WITH breaks the query into two distinct parts and stops the catresian product from forming, you'll then get the expected answer.